What are the differences between pdoc and pdoc3?
I've found what appear to be two forks of the pdoc documentation generator
pdoc (GitHub) and pdoc3 (GitHub). From
comparing the commit graphs, these appear to have split in mid-2018, but
perhaps later, or perhaps there are some commits crossing between the two.
The differences I've seen are:

pdoc:

PyPI: 1st release 2013-08-09; v14.4.0 released 2024-01-18
Github: 48 contributors, used by 2.6k, 189 forks, starred by 1.8k
Moderate commit activity over the last year
Hosted under a GitHub personal account


pdoc3:

PyPI: 1st release 2019-01-25; v0.10.0 released 2021-08-03
Github: 64 contributors, used by 3.8k, 143 forks, starred by 1.1k
Little commit activity in the last year and a half
Hosted under a GitHub organisation, but it has only one member



From the releases it looks as if pdoc3 is a fork of pdoc, Per my answer below, pdoc appears to be a fork of pdoc3 It  seems clear that pdoc3 is a fork of pdoc (though both seem to have gone for years unmaintained after the split point) but, I can't see
any explanation of why it forked or what the differences are. Given that,
and the slower pace of commits, it seems to me surprising that it has more
"users" (which I believe are projects with a requirements.txt referencing
it) than pdoc.
At any rate, I don't necessarily need the details of why the split
happened, but I would like to know what features pdoc3 provides that pdoc
doesn't, and vice versa, as well as anything else relevant to making a
choice between the two.
NOTE: I am not asking anybody to recommend one over the other, nor am I interested in such recommendations. I am interested only in facts about each that are useful in making that decision myself. (That decision will depend not only on the information provided in answers, but many other factors of the given project or purpose for which it's being considered.)

On the other hand recommendation for libraries are off-topic and even if you encapsulated in specific questions (and answer most it yourself), what you are asking is "pdoc or pdoc3?"

@KlausD. No, I am not. "pdoc or pdoc3" is a question I will answer myself (and the answer may well be different for different projects). I've clarified the question.

From various discussions on pdoc3 github issues it appears to me, that pdoc was the initial project. pdoc3 is a fork motivated by a phase where pdoc was not maintained. In the meantime both are maintained again. Since there appears to be some beef between maintainers (allegations of some 'foul play' on pdoc3 side in issue comments) I guess there won't be a merge coming anytmie soon...

A bit more specific than general maintainer conflict -- When comparing the two recently, I also looked at this issue raised in 2021  https://github.com/pdoc3/pdoc/issues/346
which the author addressed in a commit in 2024 (adding a trigger warning instead of replacing the quote?), so take that as you will. Of consideration also: the "made you look" comment in https://github.com/pdoc3/pdoc/issues/87#issuecomment-517076198. That said, people change over time and it's been many years.

Project Origins
From the CHANGELOG files, pdoc and pdoc3 appear to have diverged between release 0.3.1 (2014-12-02) and the subsequent release:

pdoc3 0.5.0 (2019-01-10). This release is relicensed as AGPL-3.0 and is a "Major refactoring, [adding] Python 3 compatibility."
pdoc 1.0.0 (2021-01-19), with an undated 0.3.2 bugfix release before that. The 1.0 release notes indicate that it's a major rewrite, dropping Python 2 support and "is now maintained by @mhils and the mitmproxy team." (Some further information and discussion is available on issue #203 pdoc is back!.

From this Python Wiki edit, it appears that pdoc was (and still is) the original project, and the pdoc3 maintainer forked it. (It's not clear who made that change, but it deleted all reference to the original project, which strikes me as a possible warning sign about the pdoc3 community. For more on this, see below.)
Technical Differences
Here are some differences between pdoc and pdoc3 that I've discovered. This is just random stuff I've picked up along the way while doing research; the list is in no way comprehensive, and some of it may not even be fully correct. (Corrections welcome; just edit this answer.)

pdoc appears to have more maintenance effort devoted towards it, given the greater frequency of commits. This is not necessarily meaningful in any way; take it with a huge grain of salt.

pdoc3 supports the additional #: comment syntax for docstrings.

pdoc supports adding @private (v14.0.0) and @public (v14.4.0) annotations to method docstrings to suppress/enforce documentation generation (the latter for e.g. methods whose name starts with an underscore).

pdoc3 supports using __pdoc__ to override docstrings. This was removed from pdoc in the 1.0.0 release (2021-01-19) because it "is rarely required."

pdoc3 can generate both PDF and HTML documentation; pdoc generates only HTML.


Community Controversies
The pdoc README has a section pdoc vs. pdoc3 claiming that pdoc3 "falsely assumes [the pdoc] name," mentioning the deletion of the original pdoc from the Python wiki, and giving other indications of some antagonism in the pdoc3 community. There's further discussion in various PRs, including pdoc#203, pdoc3#346, and [pdoc3#377]; particularly demonstrative are comments such as [1], [2] and [3].

The key difference between pdoc and pdoc3 is in their development and functionality. pdoc was the original tool for generating Python documentation, but its development has stopped, making it outdated for modern projects. In contrast, pdoc3 is an actively maintained fork of pdoc that brings several improvements, like better support for Python 3 features (including type hints and async functions), improved Markdown rendering, customizable templates, and a live-preview server for documentation. While pdoc is no longer widely used, pdoc3 has become a more reliable and feature-packed option for creating Python project documentation.

Except that the development of pdoc has clearly not stopped, given that it's getting more commits than pdoc3. Pdoc did pause development for quite a few years, but appears to have resumed in 2021.
